# How do I customize my wordpress Admin Area?

Tags: functions

I'm building a wordpress multisite which is aimed to serve as a blogging platform but I wanted to customize the admin area for my users by removing all the dafult widget. Please , Is there a wordpress function I can use to manipulate all those admin area widgets ?

Note : I don't need a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove dashboard widgets/metaboxes using the following action, [`wp_dashboard_setup`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_dashboard_setup):

#### Example 1

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']   = array();

}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets', 100);
```

Also there is the more specific core function, [`remove_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) which can be used in the same way:

#### Example 2

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'normal');

}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets', 100);
```

The above removes everything, if you want to remove only specific widgets/metaboxes, then inspect the output of the global `$wp_meta_boxes` variable, and in particalur everything within `$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']`.

```
var_dump(array_keys($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']));
var_dump(array_keys($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']));
```

In my case the keys are:

```
/*
$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'];
array (
  0 => 'dashboard_right_now',
  1 => 'dashboard_activity',
  2 => 'woocommerce_dashboard_recent_reviews',
  3 => 'woocommerce_dashboard_status',
)

$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core'];
array (
  0 => 'dashboard_quick_press',
  1 => 'dashboard_primary',
)
*/
```

You can target specific widgets/metaboxes accordingly.

By the way, a word of warning, if you use the approach where you assign an empty array to the corresponding key as shown in **example 1**, then any subsequent metaboxes that you add after the fact, should be added on a priority higher than 100 or whatever the priority is that you chose to remove them on otherwise your widget/metabox will not show. This is why it's probably a better idea to stick to the WordPress core function [`remove_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) if in doubt.

Comment: Hello ,

I have questions to ask further about this issue :

1. For example now I use the this function function remove_dashboard_widgets()  to remove a widget , how do I add my own customized widget to replace it. E.g Popular post.

2. I'm using wordpress multisite , is there a code to add so that all my users can feel the change in their admin area.

3. Difference between using add_action () and add_filter() hooks.

I'd be glad to see your response.

Thanks.